# how can I track response duration programmatically?

Tags: c#, wcf

client calls method "Foo()" of my web WCF service - and receives large byte array as a response:

```
public byte[] Foo()
{
    return new byte[10000000];
}
```

obviously, when the client reads all data, HTTP connection is closed - and if I know when did this happen, I could track the total duration of the "transmission". I know about Tracing etc - but I need to have this data programmatically, so I can display it to the user. How can I track this?

Comment: You could declare a `Stopwatch` class variable and start it before call and display the `stopwatch.Elapsed` after the call returns. If you're using threads or tasks it's a bit harder to access the main window to display statistics to user but the idea stays the same.

Comment: sure - but could you please specify WHERE exactly i should call stopwatch.Elapsed?

Comment: Do the [default WCF performance counter'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms731055(v=vs.100).aspx) deliver what you need?

Comment: Without more context I can't really tell you where. But if you have a method named foo which does the work you need for this point, call `stopwatch.Start()` before call and display `stopwatch.Elapsed` after the call is complete.

Comment: @rene - it probably will - but i have no idea how to apply it inside the code. Do you have any links with more details pls?

Comment: @maremp That really doesn't bring transport time in the equation which probably consumes a major chunk of milliseconds...

Comment: I'm telling you that without context I can't know what your code is doing and you haven't even explained the logic of your program and how the calls are preformed. You could always start the stopwatch before the call and set up an custom event which is executed when the called code is complete and in event method you call `stopwatch.stop()` and display the data or pass it to method/object which is in charge of displaying.

Comment: HTTP does support connection sharing between requests (read about the [KeepAlive header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)), so unless you have control over both client and server - you're dependent on client side configuration/setup for this functionality to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions, peformance counters and an custom behavior, but I'm not sure if they exactly answer your question because I don't take network latency into account.

**Performance counters**
The first soltuion uses the built-in [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735098%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which comes close to your requirement.
Basically you want to enable the performanceCounters for your service and then in your service get hold of one of those. Exact duration is not available but `Calls per second` is among other counters.

Make sure this is added to your service config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

In your service have a static class that holds your performancecounter. In my sample I added the static instance to the service, for real I would move that to another class.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
     // in an ideal world thisd how instancename would look like
    //ServiceName.ContractName.OperationName@first endpoint listener address

    private static PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter();

     // our static constructor
    static Service1()
    {
        // naming of the instance is garbeld due to length restrictions...
        var cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("ServiceModelOperation 4.0.0.0");
        foreach (var instance in cat.GetInstanceNames())
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(instance); // determine the instancename and copy over :-)
        }
        pc.CategoryName = "ServiceModelOperation 4.0.0.0";
        pc.CounterName = "Calls Per Second";
        pc.InstanceName = "Service1.IServ84.GetDataUsingD31@00:||LOCALHOST:2806|SERVICE1.SVC";

    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        // do interesting stuff here

        // here I have the value (in the service call but you can call this from anywhere, 
        // even from another thread. 
        // or use perfmon.exe to obtain or make a graph of the value over time...
        Trace.WriteLine(pc.NextValue().ToString()); 

        return composite;
    }
}
```

**Custom Behavior**
This custom behavior intercepts the invocation of the servicemethod and that enables the possibility to start and stop a timer and store the result.

Add the following class:

```
// custom self timing for any wcf operation
    public class Timing :Attribute, IOperationBehavior,  IOperationInvoker 
    { 
        IOperationInvoker innerOperationInvoker;
        private string operName = "";

        public Timing()
        {
        }

        public Timing(IOperationInvoker innerOperationInvoker, string name)
        {
            this.innerOperationInvoker = innerOperationInvoker;
            operName = name;
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            dispatchOperation.Invoker = new Timing(dispatchOperation.Invoker, operationDescription.Name);
        }

        public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
        {
            object value;

            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            value = innerOperationInvoker.Invoke( instance, inputs, out outputs);
            sw.Stop();
            // do what you need with the value...
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1} ms", operName,  sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            return value;
        }


        // boring required interface stuff

        public object[] AllocateInputs()
        {
            return innerOperationInvoker.AllocateInputs();
        }

        public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            return innerOperationInvoker.InvokeBegin(instance, inputs, callback, state);
        }

        public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
        {
            return innerOperationInvoker.InvokeEnd(instance, out outputs, result);
        }

        public bool IsSynchronous
        {
            get { return innerOperationInvoker.IsSynchronous; }
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

now decorate in your interface the operations that you want to store their timings with the Timing attribute:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [Timing]   // Timing for this Operation!
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use StopWatch class to find out the duration refer this msdn link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx

```
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        // your wcf functionalities
        stopWatch.Stop();
        long duration = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: `stopWatch.Elapsed` is a `TimeSpan` property which is much easier to manipulate than plain milliseconds.

Comment: my Foo() method is called from the CLIENT, i do not call it from inside my code.

Comment: @avs099 yeah, Foo() would be called by client, but using stopwatch you can calculate the total duration your wcf service took to perform your funtionalities and then you can send that duration to client or display it, however you want, i mean inside your SERVICE code.